# getting post data in a plugin

Tags: wordpress

hey guys when i am writing my plugin how do i get the POST data from the textbox and insert it into the db.

I tried but i am only able to create a table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a form like the one below

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>First Name:
        <input type="text" name="first_name" size="20">
    </p>
    <p>Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="last_name" size="20">
    </p>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button-primary" value="Create" />
    </p> 
</form>
```

Then to get the posted data you would write something like the one below.

```
<?php   
    if( isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == 'Create' ) {
        //Reads the posted values
        $first_name = $_POST[ "first_name" ];
        $last_name = $_POST[ "last_name" ];

        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "names";
        $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'f_name' => $first_name, 'l_name' => $last_name) );
}
?>
```

Depending on the information your plugin needs, the structure of the form and inserting it into the database will vary.